# A fast way to iterate through multidimensional arrays with different shapes?

Tags: arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, tensor

Vector operations can be written concisely and sped up by broadcasting a per-index operation over many indices. For example, copying a vector into a larger vector (e.g., when zero padding before FFT convolution). However, tensors (multidimensional arrays) do not have the same sequential integer indices if the arrays have different shapes. For instance, the element (1,3) in a 2x4 matrix is at flat-integer index 1*3 + 4 = 7, but the same element in a 3x5 matrix has the index 1*5 + 3 = 8 (see example below).

[image]          
[image]

So copying a matrix into a larger matrix is more tricky. If you know the shape at compile time, you can just write nested for loops:

```
typedef unsigned long*__restrict const tup_t;
typedef const unsigned long*__restrict const const_tup_t;
void nested_for_loops(const_tup_t shape) {
  // Writing x.dimension separate nested for loops: 
  for (unsigned long i0=0; i0<shape[0]; ++i0)
    for (unsigned long i1=0; i1<shape[1]; ++i1) 
      for (unsigned long i2=0; i2<shape[2]; ++i2)
        // ...
        {
          // Inside innermost loop:
          unsigned long x_index = ((i0*shape[1] + i1)*shape[2] + i2)*shape[3] /* + ... using each loop variable once */ ;
         // Perform operations on x.flat[x_index] for some tensor x 
         // in global scope: func()
        }
}
```

This follows the scheme of:

x_index= t<sub>0</sub>·s<sub>1</sub>·s<sub>2</sub>·s<sub>3</sub>·s<sub>4</sub>···s<sub>d−1</sub> + t<sub>1</sub>·s<sub>2</sub>·s<sub>3</sub>·s<sub>4</sub>···s<sub>d−1</sub> + t<sub>2</sub>·s<sub>3</sub>·s<sub>4</sub>···s<sub>d−1</sub> + ... + t<sub>d−2</sub>·s<sub>d−1</sub> 
+ t<sub>d−1</sub>.

But, this isn't possible when you don't know the dimension at compile time (because you need to know the number of for loops).  A way around this is to use tuple indexing, where you would increment the column in each iteration, and do a carry operation after you hit the border of the tensor (shape-value). An example for a tensor with shapes (2,2,2) could look like this:

[image]

However, the code involves if statements, which translate to branches in the code, to perform the carry operation.

An alternative is to simply remap the flat integer index of a tensor with shape X to the flat index in a tensor with different shape Y (this can be done with modular arithmetic):

```
inline unsigned long reindex(unsigned long index, const_tup_t shape,
                             const_tup_t new_shape, unsigned int dimension) {
  unsigned long new_index = 0;
  unsigned long new_axis_product_from_right = 1; 
  for (int i=dimension−1; index>0 && i>=0; −−i) {
    unsigned long next_axis = shape[i];
    unsigned long new_next_axis = new_shape[i];

    unsigned long next_value = index % next_axis; 

    new_index += next_value * new_axis_product_from_right;
    index /= next_axis;

    new_axis_product_from_right *= new_next_axis; 
  }
  return new_index; 
}
```

This eliminates if statements, but it does have modulo and division operations, which will not be as fast as addition or multiplication. When the tensor has a shape where all axes are powers of 2, this can be sped up by bit twiddling, replacing % operation with & and / with >>.

**The question is now, which of these methods is faster in practice?** Sure, there are libraries for multidimensional arrays (e.g., boost), but they seem to require that the dimension of the array is known at compile time and some map function like in scala or go are quite tricky when the tensors have different shapes.

Answer (score 5):

After playing around for some time led to another approach in which we can combine C++11’s variadic templates and lambda functions with template metaprogramming to unroll the desired number of for loops:

```
template <unsigned int DIMENSION>
inline unsigned long tuple_to_index_fixed_dimension(const_tup_t tup, const_tup_t shape) {
  unsigned long res = 0; unsigned int k;
  for (k=0; k<DIMENSION−1; ++k) {
    res += tup[k];
    res *= shape[k+1]; 
  }
  res += tup[k];
  return res; 
}

template <unsigned int DIMENSION, unsigned int CURRENT> 
class ForEachFixedDimensionHelper {
public:
  template <typename FUNCTION, typename ...TENSORS>
  inline static void apply(tup_t counter, const_tup_t shape, FUNCTION function, TENSORS & ...args) {
    for (counter[CURRENT]=0; counter[CURRENT]<shape[CURRENT]; ++counter[CURRENT]) 
      ForEachFixedDimensionHelper<DIMENSION−1, CURRENT+1>::template apply<FUNCTION, TENSORS...>(counter, shape, function, args...);
  } 
};

template <unsigned int CURRENT>
class ForEachFixedDimensionHelper<1u, CURRENT> { 
public:
  template <typename FUNCTION, typename ...TENSORS>
  inline static void apply(tup_t counter, const_tup_t shape, FUNCTION function, TENSORS & ...args) {
    for (counter[CURRENT]=0; counter[CURRENT]<shape[CURRENT]; ++counter[CURRENT]) 
      function(args[tuple_to_index_fixed_dimension<CURRENT+1>(counter, args.data_shape())]...); /* tensor.data_shape() is an accessor for returning the shape member. */
  } 
};

template <unsigned char DIMENSION> 
class ForEachFixedDimension { 
public:
  template <typename FUNCTION, typename ...TENSORS>
  inline static void apply(const_tup_t shape, FUNCTION function, TENSORS & ...args) {
    unsigned long counter[DIMENSION];
    memset(counter, 0, DIMENSION*sizeof(unsigned long)); 
    ForEachFixedDimensionHelper<DIMENSION,0>::template apply<FUNCTION, TENSORS...>(counter, shape, function, args...);
  } 
};
```

Note also that the tuple value and the shape can be safely declared __restrict, meaning that they point to distinct memory locations, because they will be constructed specifically for iteration and then deallocated. Values indexed by such pointers do not need to be re-read from memory when another pointer is dereferenced and changed (“pointer aliasing” problem). When invoking ForEachFixedDimension::template apply, the typename FUNCTION (possibly a lambda function) and the template parameter pack typename ...TENSORS (variadic support) can be inferred at compile time based on the contents of the tensor args... and the argument types to function.

The desired number of unrolled for loops can be looked up at runtime:

```
typedef unsigned int TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE;
template <TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE MINIMUM, TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE MAXIMUM, template <TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE> class WORKER> 
class LinearTemplateSearch {
public:
  template <typename...ARG_TYPES>
  inline static void apply(TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE v, ARG_TYPES && ... args) {
    if (v == MINIMUM)
      WORKER<MINIMUM>::apply(std::forward<ARG_TYPES>(args)...);
    else
      LinearTemplateSearch<MINIMUM+1, MAXIMUM, WORKER>::apply(v, std::forward<ARG_TYPES>(args)...);
  } 
};

template <TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE MAXIMUM, template <TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE> class WORKER >
class LinearTemplateSearch<MAXIMUM, MAXIMUM, WORKER> { 
public:
  template <typename...ARG_TYPES>
  inline static void apply(TEMPLATE_SEARCH_INT_TYPE v, ARG_TYPES && ... args) {
    assert(v == MAXIMUM);
    WORKER<MAXIMUM>::apply(std::forward<ARG_TYPES>(args)...); 
  }
};
```

Note that here, even though template recursion is used, the dimension need **not** be known until runtime. This is essentially achieved by using templates as a form of just-in-time (JIT) compilation, precomputing strategies for all dimensionalities of interest and then looking up the correct one at runtime.

So the methods were tested with **Benchmarks**. In benchmark 1, data is copied from a tensor of shape (2<sup>10</sup>, 2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>) to a tensor of shape (2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>5</sup>). In benchmark 2, an inner product between two tensors of shape (2<sup>10</sup>, 2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>) and (2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>5</sup>) is computed (visiting only tuple indices shared by both). The implementation with template recursion was compared with other alternative methods: tuple iteration; tuple iteration where the dimension is known at compile time; integer reindexing; integer reindexing where the axes are restricted to powers of 2; numpy; C-style for loops (hard coded); vectorised Fortran code; for loops in Go.

It turns out that the template recursion is faster than tuple indexing and the method used by boost:

[image]

[image]

The grey numbers represent the mean runtime and the error bars the min and max. Here are the ways those were implemented for benchmark 1 for each method:

```
// Tuple iteration (DIMENSION must be compile−time constant): vector<unsigned long> t(DIMENSION);
t.fill(0);
unsigned long k;
for (k=0; k<x.flat.size(); advance_tuple_fixed_dimension<DIMENSION>(&t[0], &x.data_shape()[0]), ++k) 
  x[k] = y[tuple_to_index_fixed_dimension<DIMENSION>(&t[0], &y.data_shape()[0])];

// boost:
x[ boost::indices[range(0, x.shape[0])][range(0,x.shape[1])][range(0,x.shape[2])] ] = y[ boost::indices[range(0,x.shape[0])][range(0,x.shape[1])][range(0,x.shape[2])] ];

! Fortran 95
x = y(1:2**5,1:2**9,1:2**9)

// Hard−coded for loops in C: unsigned long k;
for (k=0; k<x.data_shape()[0]; ++k) {
  for (unsigned long j=0; j<x.data_shape()[1]; ++j) {
    unsigned long x_bias = (k*x.data_shape()[1] + j)*x.data_shape()[2]; 
    unsigned long y_bias = (k*y.data_shape()[1] + j)*y.data_shape()[2]; 
    for (unsigned long i=0; i<x.data_shape()[2]; ++i)
      x[x_bias + i] = y[y_bias + i];
   } 
} 

// Integer reindexing:
unsigned long k;
for (k=0; k<x.flat.size(); ++k)
  x[k] = y[reindex(k, &x.data_shape()[0], &y.data_shape()[0], DIMENSION)];

// Integer reindexing (axes are powers of 2):
unsigned long k;
for (k=0; k<x.flat.size(); ++k)
  x[k] = y[reindex_powers_of_2(k, &x_log_shape[0], &y_log_shape[0], DIMENSION)];

// Tuple iteration (DIMENSION unknown at compile time):
vector<unsigned long> t(DIMENSION);
t.fill(0);
unsigned long k;
  for (k=0; k<x.flat_size(); advance_tuple(&t[0], &x.data_shape()[0], DIMENSION), ++k)
    x[k] = y[t];

# numpy (python):
x_sh = x.shape.
x = np.array(y[:x_sh[0], :x_sh[1], :x_sh[2]])

// Go:
for i:=0; i<1<<9; i++ { 
  for j:=0; j<1<<9; j++{
    for k:=0; k<1<<5; k++{ 
      x[i][j][k] = y[i][j][k]
    } 
  }
}

// TRIOT (DIMENSION unknown at compile time):
apply_tensors([](double & xV, double yV) { 
  xV = yV;
}, 
x.data_shape(), 
x, y);
```

Surprisingly, integer reindexing (even when the axes were powers of 2) was substantially slower than making a tuple counter. And the version with template recursion was sometimes much faster (including 30% faster than boost, even though boost::multi_array must know the dimension at compile time).

Here is a another examples of how you would use this nested for loop trick with template recursion:

```
double dot_product(const Tensor & x<double>, const Tensor<double> & y) { // This function written for homogeneous types, but not unnecessary 
  double tot = 0.0;
  for_each_tensors([&tot](double xV, double yV) {
    tot += xV * yV; 
  },
  x.data_shape(), /* Iterate over valid tuples for x.data_shape(); as written, this line assumes x has smaller shape*/
  x, y);
  return tot; 
}
```

And an implementations of multidimensional convolution via tuple iteration, the version with template recursion and numpy were also compared by convolving two matrices, each with shape (2<sup>8</sup>,2<sup>3</sup>).

```
Tensor<double> triot_naive_convolve(const Tensor<double> & lhs, const Tensor<double> & rhs) { 
  assert(lhs.dimension() == rhs.dimension());

  Tensor<double> result(lhs.data_shape() + rhs.data_shape() − 1ul); 
  result.flat().fill(0.0);
  Vector<unsigned long> counter_result(result.dimension());

  enumerate_for_each_tensors([&counter_result, &result, &rhs](const_tup_t counter_lhs, const unsigned int dim_lhs, double lhs_val) {
    enumerate_for_each_tensors([&counter_result, &result, &rhs, &counter_lhs, &lhs_val](const_tup_t counter_rhs, const unsigned int dim_rhs, double rhs_val) {
      for (unsigned int i=0; i<dim_rhs; ++i) 
        counter_result[i] = counter_lhs[i] + counter_rhs[i];
      unsigned long result_flat = tuple_to_index(counter_result, result.data_shape(), dim_rhs);
      result.flat()[result_flat] += lhs_val * rhs_val; 
    },
    rhs.data_shape(),
    rhs); 
  },
  lhs.data_shape(), lhs);
  return result; 
}
```

[image]

The benchmarks were timed on an 2.0 GHz Intel Core i7 chip with optimisations (-std=c++11 -Ofast -march=native - mtune=native -fomit-frame-pointer). All Fortran implementations use axes in reversed order and access data in a cache-optimised fashion, because Fortran uses column-major array format. 
Details and source code (a simple multidimensional array library where the dimension does not need to be known at compile time) can be found in this [small journal article](http://programming-journal.org/2017/1/6/).